# Creating an array of subclasses of a class

Tags: java, class

I'm trying to store all subclasses of A which are constructed by super() in the array child (in this case B). All the children are in the same package. This is my approach but I don't know how the class could store itself inside an array or pass itself as argument to super().

```
class A {
  static int i = 0;
  A[] child = new A[10]
  int someval;
  A(int val){
    someval = val;
    child[i] = ???;
    i++;
  }
}
class B extends A{
   B(){
     super(val);
   }
}
```

Is this even Possible? With my approach B will only be added when a new B() is created? Is it possible to get a complete array without creating a new object?

Comment: `this` refers to the current instance.

Comment: also, make the "child" array static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class A {
    private static final List<A> instances = new ArrayList<>();

    public A() {
        instances.add(this);
    }

    public static List<A> getInstances() {
        return instances;
    }
}
```

Now `A.getInstances()` can be called whenever you like, and will contain instances of anything that extends A.

Comment: Do I have to use a list? I rather do it with an array as i did not read about lists yet.

Comment: @derry Lists automatically grow, arrays are fixed size. So unless you want to implement logic to constantly create new arrays when the number of instances gets to big for your array you should go with a List. (As an ArrayList already has that work done for you)